# Copying a file to multiple folders in the same directory

Tags: cmd, file-moving

I have a file, lets call it EXAMPLE.DBF

The location of this file is `C:\EXAMPLE.DBF`

Now I would like to copy this file into multiple folders at another location.
These folders are `dated` Sub-directories so they are named 20140101 -  20141231 and their location would be in `d:\bootd\hello\20140101 - 20141231`
Not only that but a file named EXAMPLE.DBF already exists in the folders...so it will ask to Copy and Replace.
I will need c:\EXAMPLE to copy and replace the existing EXAMPLE.DBF in 365 folders (20140101-20141231) in a different location.

If anyone could help me out with this I will be truly grateful.

Answer (score 4):

Directly from the prompt,

```
for /d %a in (d:\bootd\hello\2014*) do copy /y C:\EXAMPLE.DBF %a\
```

Will copy C:\EXAMPLE.DBF to each directory of d:\bootd\hello\ which matches the pattern `2014*` (ie. simply starts `2014`), replacing any existing example.dbf in that subdirectory, if that is what you want to do.

To suppress the `1 file(s) copied` messae generate for each, simply append `>nul` to the above line.

Comment: Magoo you are legitimately rad! By append do you mean the script should look like: 

for /d %a in (d:\bootd\hello\2014*) do copy /y C:\EXAMPLE.DBF %a\ >null

?

Comment: I tried this out and was very hopeful...although no matter what I try the "EXAMPLE.DBF" can never be found. This is  definitely pathed correctly. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ Magoo

Thank you VERY VERY much Magoo...this is such a time saver...

If you have time I have another question if you could hep me out:

I need to run an executable on all of the dated sub-directories once I input the files...

I would usually do this by a cmd like this:

d:\bootd\hello\executables\example.exe /date 20140131

**The problem with this is that I can only execute the executable on one folder at a time**

Comment: The `>nul` directs any outout to *nowhere* (it's designed that way) Note however that there;s only one `l` - with two, it will create a file named `null`. The extension question - it's quite easy, but unrelate to your oginal question. The object of SO is to generate a databse of questions and answers, so you should ask a further question for FREE

Comment: Thanks @Magoo ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283066/how-do-you-run-an-executable-on-multiple-folders

Comment: In case if the name of the source folder has spaces, you can use double quotes like this to do the work: FOR /d %A IN (D:\bootd\hello\2014*) DO xcopy /y "C:\Program Files\EXAMPLE.DBF" %a\

Answer (score 1):

Just a small addition to @Magoo's answer;

in case the destination folders have spaces in their names, use double quotes like this:
for /d %a in (d:\bootd\hello\2014*) do copy /y C:\EXAMPLE.DBF "%a\"

and as pointed out by @ian0411, in case source folder has spaces in its name, use double quotes like this:
for /d %a in (d:\bootd\hello\2014*) do copy /y "C:\EXAMPLE.DBF" %a\