# How do you run an executable on multiple folders?

Tags: exe, directory

- I need to run an executable on multiple folders. Lets say the
  EXECUTABLE is called "example.exe".
- The group of folders are DATED sub-directories that use a scheme of 20140101-20141231. A year of dated sub-directories. 365 Folders in total.
- I usually run the command like: `d:\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\EXECUTABLES\example.exe /DATE 20140101`

The problem w/ this method is that I am ONLY able to run this executable on ONE dated sub-directory or folder at a time...any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question, because we can't see your screen from where we're sitting or read your mind, and therefore we have no idea how you try to *run an executable*. Therefore, we can't tell you how to *run* it differently. I have a suggestion: let's say you [edit] your question and be more specific, so that we can try to help you solve the problem you're having. :-)

Comment: Do you want to run the executable in parallel in the different folders? or just have a file that will run the executable for all the folders (e.g.: a batch file)?

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the prompt,

```
for /d %a in (d:\your\subdirectory\2014*) do d:\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\EXECUTABLES\example.exe /DATE %%~na
```

or

```
for /d %a in (d:\your\subdirectory\2014*) do call d:\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\EXECUTABLES\example.exe /DATE %%~na
```

or

```
for /d %a in (d:\your\subdirectory\2014*) do start /w "" d:\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\EXECUTABLES\example.exe /DATE %%~na
```

may suit.

(I've assumed you want the parameter following the `/date` switch to be the name of the directory; also `2014*` assumes you want this to run on all directories named starting `2014`.)