# copy file to multiple subdirectories in same directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd, file-copying

Expanding upon this example: [Copying a file to multiple folders in the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271432/copying-a-file-to-multiple-folders-in-the-same-directory)

I want to copy all file .txt from `C:\Newfolder\` to folder `C:\Output\*\rack\*\cloth`

example for destination folder:

```
C:\Output\name1\rack\nick1\cloth
C:\Output\name2\rack\nick2\cloth
.
.
C:\Output\name100\rack\nick100\cloth
```

so I have tried this:

```
FOR /D %%1 IN (C:\Output\*) DO (
    IF EXIST "%%1\rack" (
        COPY /Y C:\Newfolder\*.txt "%%1\rack\*\cloth"
    )
)
```

the problem all txt file doesn't copied to destination folder

Comment: Do not use decimal digits for `for` variables, use letters (e. g., `%%I`)! Anyway, why are you using a `for /D` loop for resolving the first wild-card but for the second? Let me recommend to put quotation marks around all paths, and to use `%%~I` rather than `%%I`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the same `FOR /D` method for each unknown subfolder name then you should get to where you want to be:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
FOR /D %%A IN ("C:\Output\*") DO IF EXIST "%%A\rack\" FOR /D %%B IN ("%%A\rack\*"
) DO IF EXIST "%%B\cloth\" COPY /Y "C:\Newfolder\*.txt" "%%B\cloth"
```